# What I Should To Learn To Develop Chrome Apps ?

Tags: chrome-web-store

What I Should To Learn To Develop Chrome Apps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You meant in which language? Your question is not very clear. Well if you want to learn develop chrome apps you need to know: Javascript, HTML, CSS ( These are NOT programming languages, and they are easy to learn )

Here you have some nice reading:

http://www.vikitech.com/2398/create-chrome-web-apps

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Yeah ! That's What I Meant :) Thx a lot